# How to import python module numpy globally on Mac

Tags: python, numpy, import

I'm using python2.7 and os x 10.10.3

Every time I want to import numpy or scipy, I get this error:

```
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

But When I open python in /usr/bin, I can import those modules successfully. Once I'm out of this directory, I get this error.

PS: I find that in /usr/bin, there're both python2.7 and python2.6, but I use the command "python2.7" to start python.

Comment: what do `which python` and `which -a python` output

Comment: You can't install it *"globally"* if you mean *"for every interpreter"*. Instead, look into `virtualenv`s as a handy way of controlling precisely what interpreter is used and what packages are available on a project-by-project basis.

Comment: Check if in your $PATH , the wrong is there , if so try fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

I also have os 10.10.3, and there's the package location :

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy

i suggest you try look for 'bumpy' folder under

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

and if you don't have it there, you should consider install the package manually using macports

sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I tried macports, it installed another python for me, and numpy is still not working. Now I'm trying pip to install it.